# error in spark_sql with "value as is not a member of object"

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have the case class  like:

Hotel (id: String , name: String, cc1: String, city_preferred: String)

the csv is like:

| id | name | cc1 | city_hotel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1949417 | apart A | pl | Sopot |
| 2023862 | apart B | es | Granada |
| 1967734 | apart C | hr | Ici |

and I have to show the id, name and country but only with the hotels in Spain

I try:

```
val hotelsSpain = Hotel.as("Hoteles")
                      .select("cc1", "id", "name", "city_hotel")
                      .where("cc1" == "es")

display(hotelsSpain)
```

but the code return me

> error: value as is not a member of object Hotel
> val hotelsSpain = *Hotel.as*("Hoteles")

I think it is a little error but I don't see it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your schema, the column is defined as "city_prefered" (sic), but your code contains "city_hotel"

Looks to me that this error is simply telling you that "city_hotel" doesn't exist on this object

Comment: nop, sorry I have a mistake in the name of the column

Comment: is the "esp" as cc1 instead of "es" also a typo? This could also be the source of the error

Comment: no, the error is in the part of .as("Hoteles")